# MongoDB Map class from nested elements in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I've registered a class to pull addresses out of the a restaurants collection:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<RestaurantAddress>(map =>
{
    map.MapMember(c => c.Id).SetElementName(("_id"));
    map.MapMember(c => c.Building).SetElementName("address.building");
    map.MapMember(c => c.Street).SetElementName("address.street");
    map.MapMember(c => c.ZipCode).SetElementName("address.zipcode");
});
```

The Mongo document looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56bb82621ff72e0d9ba267cb"),
    "address" : {
        "building" : "6409",
        "coord" : [ 
            -74.005289, 
            40.628886
        ],
        "street" : "11 Avenue",
        "zipcode" : "11219"
    },
    "borough" : "Brooklyn",
    "cuisine" : "American ",
    "grades" : [ 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2014-07-18T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "grade" : "A",
            "score" : 12
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2013-07-30T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "grade" : "A",
            "score" : 12
        }
    ],
    "name" : "Regina Caterers",
    "restaurant_id" : "40356649"
}
```

When I get the document, the nested elements are all null though:

```
[Test]
public void DeserializeToAddress()
{
    var collection = _database.GetCollection<RestaurantAddress>("grades");

    var address = collection.Find(a => a.Id == new ObjectId("56bb82621ff72e0d9ba267cb")).Limit(1).Single();

    Assert.That(address.Id, Is.Not.Null);
    Assert.That(address.Building, Is.Not.Null);
    Assert.That(address.Street, Is.Not.Null);
}
```

How should I be referencing nested elements?

The class to serialize into is:

```
internal class RestaurantAddress
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Building { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public Point CoordsPoint { get; set; }
}
```

Currenlty, I don't have anything for hyrating the `CoordsPoint` object.  That's for a later excercise.

Comment: Can you post your class definition?

Answer (score 1):

We currently don't support pulling nested elements out into a parent document. This would be a feature request. You can file that at jira.mongodb.org under the CSHARP project. Alternatively, you can write a custom serializer to handle this particular scenario if you'd like.

Craig

Comment: Cheers, I'll add a request.  Do I click 'create issue' or is there another link?

Comment: How do you mean you support pulling nested documents? Am I not able to deserialize a nested object especially member of nested arrays to a c# Object?